# getting curl: (52) Empty reply from server when run from jenkins job (only an issue with the job that i used docker run )

Tags: bash, shell, curl, docker, jenkins

I have seemed to run into some issues with curl, I have created a freestyle Jenkins job to build and deploy a basic hello world docker image.
The build and deployment work fine, but I ran a curl command to test the deployment and it always fails the job

below is the script that I ran

`npm install 
docker build -t rvarg11/helloworld2 .
docker rm -f dockertest
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name dockertest rvarg11/helloworld2
curl -f http://127.0.0.1:3000`

the jobs fail with the below error when Jenkins reach the curl command

- curl -f http://127.0.0.1:3000
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  curl: (52) Empty reply from server

**this is only an issue when I try curl from the same job that I used for build** , if I create a separate job and try to curl it works without any issues 
I am new to all this and this is the first time I am posting a question hope I have explained everything properly [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfLkL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Bv4.png)

Comment: if it is working from another job, what strikes is that jenkins would have a time lag in starting another job, by which time the application is ready to accept request and curl goes through. so giving a delay before curl may be something you can try.

Comment: i put a 10 s delay and it worked thanks :)

Comment: I have added my suggestion in the answer you can 'accept' the answer, so that folks who have similar issue can get the suggestion easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is working fine from another Jenkins job, it is because there is a time delay for Jenkins executor to pick up the next job by which time the application is ready to accept request causing the subsequent job to be success. An appropriate delay in the current job before making the curl request should solve the problem.